# "Failed to mount Windows share" while booting Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

On boot, I get an error message:

> Error: Failed to mount Windows share

`mount` is trying to mount a Windows XP machine that no longer exists. It happens automatically on reboot, there is nothing in `fstab` or `smb.conf` files. As the call is to a nonexistent media directory, I checked Totem player's playlist and nothing appears there.

I don't know how to figure out what is making this call.

Answer (score 0):

update to question.

if i open nautilus file browser, there are links under GO menu to nonexistent windows xp computer.  if i clear history and reboot, the links are back again.

what file holds the data, links, that GO menu uses?